# Global array undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, global

I have a simple jQuery script to show/hide list elements accordion-style along with a global boolean array to save which lists are shown/hidden. However, when switching from show/hiding different sublists, the boolean array goes undefined, ie (I call function with form_nav_links to show that list, then when I try to show help_nav_links right after, the array is undefined and requires an extra click). Can someone help me fix this? Here is what I have:

```
var listsOn = Boolean[2];
listsOn = [false, false];
var form_links = 0, help_links = 1;

function toggleView(subList) {
    var i;

    switch(subList){
        case "form_nav_links":
            i = form_links;
            break;
        case "help_nav_links":
            i = help_links;
            break;
        };

    if(listsOn[i]){
        $("." + subList).slideUp(1000);
        listsOn[i] = false;
        }
    else {
        $("." + subList).slideDown(1000);
        listsOn[i] = true;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Boolean[2];` in javascript means nothing useful.

Comment: How is that called ? Can you set a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: use slideToggle() and never use globals :)

Comment: ^^ well that's just sooo much better, varela. That beautifully knocks it down to 1 line =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using slideToggle() instead

Answer (score 1):

You really ought to be using an associative array here:

```
var listsOn = {
  form_nav_links: false,
  help_nav_links: false
};

function toggleView(subList) {
  if(typeof listsOn[subList] !== 'undefined') {
    if(listsOn[subList]{
        $("." + subList).slideUp(1000);
        listsOn[subList] = false;
    }
    else {
        $("." + subList).slideDown(1000);
        listsOn[subList] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, strict equal to 'undefined' string, what else you expect from typeof?

Comment: ah, I had that originally but then got stuck trying to access the bools like listsOn.blah (I'm less than a week into JS)

Comment: @varela: no reason not to use strict equal and it's easier to have an established habit of using strict equality than switching and leaving it to the maintainer to determine whether an unstrict equality operator is acceptable.